# Theorems about piercing numbers

Tags: co.combinatorics

I'm searching for results relating to piercing numbers. One example of what I'm looking for is this theorem: any VC Class which is k-consistent has a bounded piercing number.

However, searching Google/arxiv only gives me the above theorem and a bunch of papers about convex sets. What are some other results/papers related to piercing numbers? Ideally, they should be combinatorial in nature as opposed to geometric.

Background: I'm asking this because I'm currently doing research on the possible connection between VC Classes and compression schemes.

Comment: Btw, I currently have to leave for a few hours, so don't worry if your answer isn't immediately accepted - I'll accept/vote up answers when I get back.

Comment: What is k-consistent? There is a theorem of and Haussler-Welzl that $\tau\le O(VC(dim) \tau^* \log\tau^*)$, see eg. Matousek's book on Discrete Geometry, 10.2.7.

Comment: @Lopsy: You might try to sharpen your question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the most general results is that of Alon and Kalai in their 1995
paper "*Bounding the piercing number*,"
solving the 1957 "$(p,q)$ problem" of Hadwiger and Debrunner.
The show that, *if* there is a family of sets $\cal F$
(condition on these sets later) so that any $p$ of them
contain a subset of $q$ with a non-empty intersection, $p \ge q$,
*then* there is a set of at most $c$ points
that intersects each member of $\cal F$, i.e., $c$ points pierce $\cal F$.
The condition on $\cal F$ is that each member is the union of at most $k$ compact,
convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$.  Of course $c$ depends on all the parameters
$\lbrace p, q, k, d \rbrace$, but the important point is that $c$ is finite.
This is a geometric result, rather than a purely combinatorial one, but
it is very broad.
[*Discrete and Computational Geometry*, Vol. 13, No. 3–4, 245–256, 1995](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02574042).

You might also look at "the Colorful Caratheodory Theorem," described, e.g., at [Gil Kalai's blog](https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/colorful-caratheodory-revisited/).

Answer (score 4):

The result you are looking for is proved in Matousek's paper "bounded VC-dimension implies a fractional Helly theorem". It is theorem 4 there.

Matousek explains how to adapt Alon and Kleitman's proof of the $(p,q)$-theorem mentioned in Joseph's answer from families of convex sets to families of finite VC-dimension.

Comment: Here are two links to Matoušek's paper: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.10.6099 , http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1005789 .